# Linear mixed models in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

Here is a reproducible dataset :

```
db = data.frame(
condition = c("Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Experimental","Experimental","Experimental","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Experimental","Experimental","Experimental","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Experimental","Experimental","Experimental","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline","Experimental","Experimental","Experimental","Baseline","Baseline","Baseline"),
partner = c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John","Albert","John","John","John","John","John","John","Albert","Charles","Charles","Jay","Jay","Jay","John","John","Albert","Charles","Charles","Jay","Jay","Jay","Charles","Charles","Jay","Jay","Jay","Albert","Charles","Charles","Jay","Jay","Jay"),
time = sample(c(1:50),40))
```

I would like to test, for each *partner*, if they are spending significantly more *time* in Experimental *condition* than in Baseline *condition*.

I believe this is done using the *lmer* function, here is what I have so far :

```
library(lme4)
m0 <- lmer(time ~ condition + (1|partner), data=db, REML = 0)
summary(m0)
```

I do not know how to obtain a detailed list of p-values for each *partner* when comparing the Experimental against Baseline *condition*.

Ideally, I would like to have an output as follows:

```
                  Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)        167.217    167.979  212.490   0.995  0.32064   
partnerJohn        125.674     50.390  212.490   2.494  0.01339 * 
partnerAlbert      -70.225    233.364  212.490  -0.301  0.76377   
partnerCharles     -29.141    218.373  212.490  -0.133  0.89397
```

Could anyone give me some help as to which analysis I should use to get an output like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a chi-squared test. You've confused yourself because the categories "baseline" and "experimental" are physically different from the time measurements, and because you have several partners. Simply compare expected versus actual time in each condition using chi-squared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to see what amount per baseline unit each parter spends in the experimental condition, then this would be the way to do it:

```
m0 <- lm(time ~ condition*partner, data=db)
summary(m0)
```

And this would be the results:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-28.000  -6.938   2.659  10.188  24.750 

Coefficients:
                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                            15.500     10.187   1.522    0.138
conditionExperimental                  -9.000     14.407  -0.625    0.537
partnerCharles                         18.500     13.151   1.407    0.169
partnerJay                              8.682     11.074   0.784    0.439
partnerJohn                             9.750     11.003   0.886    0.382
conditionExperimental:partnerCharles   10.000     17.839   0.561    0.579
conditionExperimental:partnerJay      -14.182     20.832  -0.681    0.501
conditionExperimental:partnerJohn      14.500     16.635   0.872    0.390

Residual standard error: 14.41 on 32 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2588,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.09671 
F-statistic: 1.596 on 7 and 32 DF,  p-value: 0.1723
```

You would read this as the baseline is the intercept of 15.5 Plus or minus the coefficient for each partner.

If you are looking for the individual partners baseline, then add or subtract `partnerJay` or `partnerCharles`.

If you are looking for the experimental time, add or subtract the `conditionExperimental:partnerJohn` of `conditionExperimental:partnerJay` to the intercept.

You multiply  the parter by the condition because you are looking for the interaction between each partner at each condition level.

This is just s simple multiple linear regression. You would read the coefficients and error the same as a simple linear regression.